# Join two columns in Primary Key with only character from 1 column in SQL

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, composite-primary-key

I have table faculty where I have primary key (FirstName, LastName).
In sections table the values of foreign key for Faculty table is written as  InitialOfFirstName.LastName

For example:

If primary key is (Will, Jones)
In another table it is used as (W.Jones)

How shall I constraint this in two tables?

Comment: You can't. End of story. For a Foreign Key to reference another table's Primary Key the value **needs** to be the same. Also, a name is a poor choice of a primary key; names are *not* unique and they can and *do* change; and having to change the value of your primary key when it's used as a foreign key constraint is almost always a world of "hurt".

Comment: You don't. Fix your schema now and do it correctly. Names can change. Your project will collapse when that happens.

Comment: Plus the fact that  the *other* value is "less precise" than the key candidate, so when you have "A.Smith" how do you know it's "Smith, Angela" or "Smith, Anthony"?